# How to find last occurrence of a substring using Kusto Query Language?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

Kusto Query Language provides [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/indexoffunction) function (searches the first occurrence). The question is how to find the last occurrence of some substring.

Answer (score 6):

I guess, the best you can do is (example on how to search for last "cde" in "abcdefabcdef"):

```
datatable (name:string, lookup:string)["abcdefabcdef", "cde"]
| project value = strlen(name) - indexof(reverse(name), reverse(lookup)) - strlen(lookup)
```

Comment: i was able to use the reverse() logic, it worked for my case. In Log analytics, i had to find the last set of string split with "/".  i used  

reverse( substring(reverse(InputString),0, indexof(reverse(InputString),"/")));

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the result of `countof` to the occurence parameter of `indexof`:

```
let lastIndexof = (input:string, lookup: string) {
    indexof(input, lookup, 0, -1, countof(input,lookup))
};
print lastIndexof("abcdefabcdef", "cde")
```

Comment: Nice workaround =) I think start_index is zero based. It's not specified in the documentation but since this function returns zero based index then my expectation is that it zero based here as well.

Comment: This worked when i used this as such in azure log analytics, when i used within a substring, i received an error stating, the countof() value should be a scalar. i tried using toscalar() but still it didn't resolve in my case. but @Dmitry Matveev logic worked in that case.